# Use Scala types in Java (type mismatch)

Tags: java, scala

In Java I'm trying to use a type defined in Scala, but I'm getting 'type mismatch' errors. I assume this is because of Java's type erasure, but is there some way to get around this?

In Scala I have this type

```
Type[T]
```

And an Action class which uses this type to define it's value type to guarantee the value is of the defined type.

```
class Action[T](tpe: Type[T], value: T)
```

Now when there is something like a BooleanType for example, then the Action only allows true of false values.

```
case object BooleanType extends Type[Boolean]
new Action(BooleanType, true) // ok
new Action(BooleanType, 1)    // compile error
```

We would like to be able to use this from Java as well. In Java I could define a type either as a class

```
class TimestampType implements Type[Long]
```

or as an enum to have a singleton like the 'case object's in Scala

```
enum LongType implements Type[Long] { LongType; }
```

But when I now try to use these in an Action

```
new Action(new TimestampType, 1L)
new Action(LongType.LongType, 1L)
```

both statements give a compile error

> :12: error: type mismatch;
>    found   : TimestampType
>    required: Type[Any]
>   Note: Long <: Any (and TimestampType <: Type[Long]), but trait Type is invariant in type T.
>   You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
>                 new Action(new TimestampType, 1L)

The cause is probably because the type erasure of the Java class.
I have played with using +T and -T variance, but this does either not give the functionality which I want or does not compile.
I also tried to use `[T : ClassTag]` for the Action class, but this does not resolve the issue.

Is there any way to be able to have Java implementations of Scala types?
Is there a better way to try to enforce the type of the value is allowed or compatible with a defined Type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you have specified the wrong type.You have declared it as:

```
class TimestampType implements Type[java.lang.Long]
```

but instead in scala, you do `new Action(new TimestampType, 1L:scala.Long)`. `java.lang.Long` is different from `scala.Long`. Hence error.

The below works:
In Java:

```
public class IntTyp implements Typ<scala.Int> {}
```

In scala,

```
val b = new Action[Int](new IntTyp, 1)
```

or vice-versa:

```
public class LongTyp implements Typ<Long> {}
val c = new Action[java.lang.Long](new LongTyp, 1L)
```

Comment: `scala.Int` can not be used from Java, since it isn't really a JVM type.